# Creación de Triggers en MySQL para un proyecto

Tags: mysql, trigger, sql, insert

Muy buenas.

Necesito una serie de Triggers que me permitan insertar información en distintas tablas, esta seria la estructura.

---

```
Table: programae
Columns:
idProgramaE int(11) PK 
programaEducativo varchar(90)
```

---

```
Table: alumno
Columns:
idAlumno int(11) AI PK 
nombre varchar(100) 
Grado int(2) 
Grupo varchar(45) 
idProgramaE int(11) FK
```

---

```
Table: registro
Columns:
idRegistro int(6) AI PK 
entrada datetime 
Matricula int(6) 
idMatricula int(11) FK
```

---

Necesito que, **cuando una persona inserte "matricula". Se active un trigger que inserte un nuevo "idAlumno" en la tabla "alumno" si este no existe.**

*Por ultimo*

Tengo una bitácora de la siguiente manera

---

```
Columns:
id_bitacora int(11) AI PK 
fecha datetime 
ejecutor varchar(20) 
actividad_realizada varchar(50)
```

---

**Necesito los triggers necesarios para que la bitácora funcione.**

Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Por favor considera incluir en tu pregunta el código que has intentado hasta ahora complementado con el error que produce (si fuera el caso) o donde te quedaste trancado. Eso elevará la posibilidad de obtener respuestas. También te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para familiarizarte con el funcionamiento del sitio y ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar lo que has intentado, por favor?

Comment: `declare matri int; 
set matri  = (Select Matricula from registro getLastRecord ORDER BY idRegistro DESC LIMIT 1);
if (select idAlumno from alumno where idAlumno = matri) = null then
insert into alumno(idAlumno) values (matri);
end if;`